# Oracle- save dates with correct centuryinfo

Tags: oracle, date, save

I am trying to insert nvarchar2 values into my oracle Date field. When my source nvarchar2 value is '20701130', I want to save it as '30/11/2070' in my oracle column. And, if the source value is '21150529', I want to save it as '29/05/2115'.

I tried different formatting options to achieve this, but the year is always getting saved as two digits and is not indicating the correct century.

One of my Queries:

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (MY_DATE_FIELD)
VALUES(TO_DATE('21061030', 'RRRR-MM-DD'));
```

Now, when I select after the above query, I get the result as 30/10/06 which is not we want, it should be '30/10/2106'.

Comment: what's the result for this query : `select p.value from nls_instance_parameters p where p.PARAMETER = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT'` -> _'DD/MM/RRRR'_ or _'DD/MM/RR'_?

Answer (score 0):

You can go about it in many ways:

You alter the session date format itself to a format you want to achieve like :

***ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'RRRR-MM-DD';***

Another approach is once you have achieved a date from a string passed using to_date then you can again add to_char to display the date in a format you want.

To_date will convert your string to a date using the format you have provided but while selecting it will still display the date as per the format provided in the session that's why we use To_char to change it to a format we want to display it into.

***select to_char(TO_DATE('21061030', 'RRRR-MM-DD'),'RRRR-MM-DD') "DATE" from dual;***

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help.

I have pasted my SQL below if anyone is interested.

```
-- To insert into table
UPDATE MY_TABLE SET MY_DATE_FLD = TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('21061030', 'RRRR-MM-DD'),'DD-MM-YYYY') ;

-- To read from the table, this gave me the result 30/01/2106
select TO_CHAR(DATE_FLD,'DD/MM/YYY') AS START_DATE from MY_TABLE;
```

Appreciate the help.
Kiran.